# Which is the correct resolution, ppi and fromat for images in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, resolution, screen-resolution

I really dont know if this is the correct place for this quiestion but I dont know another place to find the exact answer.

Im working on an iphone project, the designers sent me the material in really high resolutions: for example for iphone 4 they sent me 2667 × 4000 images(up to 5mb) (for the background) and for iphone 5 2667 × 4733 (up to 6mb) and there are like 15 viewcontrollers using one of this images (different for each) all of them in PNG.

So the problem is that I found out that in my device settings the app is 155mb of size and Im assuming this is caused by the HD resolution images

So I want to know which is the correct ppi(inches per pixel), the format its png thats ok, and the correct resolution for each device.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here: http://dpi.lv/

Sorry its an off- site link, but it is quite nice: They run a database of devices, their resolutions and ppi. And if you look at it with the device in question give you the specs for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the required resolution of the devices here- 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1